# Accordion component in AEM throwing error while building the project

Tags: arrays, aem, accordion, sightly

Recently I was using the out of box accordion component in my AEM project (6.5). The component is working fine in author and publish mode. But when I'm trying to build the project using Maven, I'm getting the below error.

```
**${item.name in accordion.expandedItems}: extraneous input 'in' expecting {'}','.','&&','||','[','@'}**
```

There are no other detailed information regarding the error. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might reference an older version of HTL/Sightly in your `pom.xml` that has no support for `in` relational operator (which was [added](https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/issues/56) in version 1.4 of the spec).